# Help for the installation of "stripe-php" library manually for stripe extension?

Tags: magento2, php, helper, stripe, request

Can anyone help me please? I have installed Stripe module but not showing at the frontend.[image]

Comment: Download from [here][1]  and unzip at app/code make sure name name registration.php


  [1]: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-magento2-releases

Comment: Again getting error. @ZahidHussainMagento Please check by clicking the below link:
https://ibb.co/qB0DL9d

Comment: If you have already stripe please remove it using composer remove strip/strip.
download strip from above link unzip and add at app/code/Vendor/Name.
 than make sure also permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have done all but still stripe is not showing at the checkout page 
@ZahidHussainMagento

Comment: Configure it from admin side

Comment: I have tried my best but not working. Do you want to see any setting ?@ZahidHussainMagento

Comment: Go to sales->payment method -> select Stripe from payment methods list.